# Adaptive cards web chat: Validate one input field number is greater that the other input field number

Tags: validation, botframework, adaptive-cards, web-chat

I am trying to add validation to make sure one input field number is greater that the other input field number. I want to do this with in json but I haven't found any documentation around that. thank you!

the only validation options  I found are 1. required 2. Regex validation of input. I have not found any thing that can help validate dependent fields.